# How does the similarity function of SpaCy work?

Tags: nlp, spacy, sentence-similarity

How does the similarity function of SpaCy work. Does it take into account the POS tagging, dependency parsing etc. while finding the similarity score between two sentences? If it doesn't then how can i use the features provided by SpaCy for a better semantic classification of sentences?

Comment: Have you checked the docs? https://spacy.io/api/

Comment: I did visit the docs but there was no specific mention of how the similarity function worked. It's just that it uses the glove vector representations for calculating the cosine similarity. And i dont think Glove has features like POS and other feautres like Elmo. Hence this question..

Comment: This might help you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304217/how-is-the-similarity-method-in-spacy-computed